# Run group testng test through console in gradle

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, testng

I have some tests(testng annotations):

```
@Test(groups={"Example"})
public void Test1(){...}

@Test(groups={"Example"})
public void Test2(){...}

@Test(groups={"Example2"})
public void Test3(){...}
```

And in build.gradle file I can run group test next way:

```
task runTests(type: Test){
    useTestNG() {
       suites "src/test/resources/testng.xml"
       includeGroups "Example"
    }
}
```

But I want to run this "Example" group as parameter through gradle command line like we do with single test `gradle -Dtest.single=... test`.
Is there a possibility in gradle to do something like `gradle -Dtest.groups=Example test` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you shouldn't use `gradlew -Dtest.single=... test`, but `gradlew test --tests ...`.

You could easily configure yourself such a possibility by evaluating a project property like `includeGroups(project.findProperty('testGroups') ?: 'DefaultGroup')` and then you can do `gradlew test -P testGroups=Example`.

Comment: when I set includeGroups(testGroups ?: 'DefaultGroup')  I get an error :
```Could not get unknown property 'testGroups' for object of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGOptions.```